# How to add a derived list to a model object

Tags: mapstruct

I'd like to add a derived list to a DTO/model object when mapping from an entity. For example, I have an entity class named Company that has a list of Employees. I'd like for the Company Model object to contain the list of Employees as well as a list of Employees who are Managers. (This is not my actual class names, but this type of thing is what I'm trying to do). So, I want the Company DTO to have a list of Employees and a list of Managers where the Managers is a subset of Employees that is derived by filtering the list of Employees.

I tried using a mapping expression and a default method. However, I need to use the EmployeeMapper and it seems that I don't have access to the mapper.

Here's what I tried...

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {EmployeeMapper.class})
public interface CompanyMapper extends IEntityMapper<CompanyModel, Entity> {

    @Mapping(expression = "java(deriveManagers(model))", target = "managers")
    EntityModel toModel(Company company);

    default List<EmployeeModel> deriveManagers(Company company) {
        List<EmployeeModel> managers = new ArrayList<EmployeeModel>();

        company.getEmployees().forEach(nextEmployee -> {
          if (nextEmployee.getJobTitle().equals(JobTitle.MANAGER)) {
            managers.add(this.EmployeeMapper.toModel(nextEmployee);
          }
        });

        return managers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do this processing in the DTO/Model object rather than in the Mapper. The list can be derived as a subset of the EmployeeModel objects in the CompanyModel object. Therefore, I think that this is the right place to derive this list. It is not really a mapping from Entity to Model object as much as it is a derived attribute in the Model object.